# ALGEBRAIC STRUCTURES : Let $G$ be a group and $a,b \in G$ . For $ax = b$; where $x$ is unknown :

Tags: group-theory

(a) What is the solution of the above expression(value of $x$) ?

$a^{-1}ax = a^{-1}b$ $\ \ \ $ (Left multiply by $a^{-1}$)

$(a^{-1}a)x$ = $a^{-1}b$

$ex$ = $a^{-1}b$

$x = a^{-1}b$

(b) Prove that the solution you found in (a) is unique.

Assume by contradiction that we have two different $x_1$ and $x_2$

$x_1=a^{-1}b$
$x_2=a^{-1}b$

$ax_2=aa^{-1}b$

$ax_2=b$

by substitution

$x_2=a^{-1}ax_2$

$x_1=x_2$

is true or not ???

Comment: The proof of a) is okay and allready shows directly that $x$ is unique. So question b) is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer on a) is correct. If $ax=b$ in a group then we arrive indeed at $x=a^{-1}b$ by application of the axioms:

- $ax=b$
- $a^{-1}(ax)=a^{-1}b$ (the existence of an inverse)
- $(a^{-1}a)x=a^{-1}b$ (associativity)
- $ex=a^{-1}b$ where $e$ denotes the identity
- $x=a^{-1}b$

So based on $ax=b$ we found that $x=a^{-1}b$.

This allready states directly that $x$ is unique. If $ax_1=b=ax_2$ then we simply have: $$x_1=a^{-1}b=x_2$$